# Docker Nginx and Angular getting Welcome page

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my Angular Spring app to docker. For angular I used nginx and everytime I access any root from angular app I get the "Welcome to nginx" page. I looked it up already on internet, but I could not find a solution

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html

  }
}
```

**Dockerfile for angular**

```
FROM node:13.6.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install && npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```